# Creating a subquery to retrieve data from more than one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I have code as shown below; I need to search new variables I created as `cour` and `year` in my stored procedure

```
SELECT 
    ,s.kid, ep.exper_id, ep.exper_name, mp.md_name, 
    mo.md_option_id, kk.external_id,
    mv.completed_id,
    COUNT(ce.times_observed) AS countoftimes,
    CASE
        WHEN kid = '7180' THEN '044986'
        WHEN kid = '7800' THEN '044984' 
    END AS cour,
    CASE 
        WHEN CE.yid = '2024' THEN '2023-24'
        WHEN CE.yid = '2023' THEN '2022-23'  
    END AS [year]
FROM
    ks.reqe_md_pool mp, ks.reqe_md_options mo, 
    ks.reqe_md_values mv, ks.reqe_experiences_pool ep,
    ks.reqe_completed_experiences ce
LEFT JOIN
    ks.oasis_person kk ON kk.person_id = ce.student_id
LEFT JOIN  
    ks.oasis_schedule s ON ce.schedule_id = s.schedule_id, 
    ks.reqe_list_version lv 
WHERE 
    ep.exper_id = '1492'
    AND mv.md_id = mp.md_id 
    AND ce.exper_id = ep.exper_id 
    AND ce.completed_id = mv.completed_id 
    AND mv.md_option_id = mo.md_option_id 
    AND ce.list_version_id = lv.list_version_id 
GROUP BY 
    s.did, s.cid, s.lid, ep.exper_id, ep.exper_name,
    mp.md_id, mp.md_name, mo.md_option_id, mo.md_option_order, 
    mo.md_option_name, ce.student_id, mv.text_answer, mv.md_value_id,
    mv.completed_id, CE.YID, kk.external_id
```

How can I search for `year` and `cour` in stored procedure created in SQL?

I tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (*code at the top* ) 
WHERE
    cour = @cour
    AND year = @year
```

Then I tried cross apply, which worked with `year`, but didn't work with `cour`, because that able is in left join

```
SELECT 
    ,s.kid, ep.exper_id, ep.exper_name, mp.md_name, 
    mo.md_option_id, kk.external_id,
    mv.completed_id
 
FROM
    ks.reqe_md_pool mp, ks.reqe_md_options mo, 
    ks.reqe_md_values mv, ks.reqe_experiences_pool ep,
    ks.reqe_completed_experiences ce
LEFT JOIN
    ks.oasis_person kk ON kk.person_id = ce.student_id
LEFT JOIN  
    ks.oasis_schedule s ON ce.schedule_id = s.schedule_id, 
    ks.reqe_list_version lv 
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
       case WHEN kid='7180' then '044986'
            WHEN kid='7800' then '044984'
 
           END AS UCFCOURSEID)
               C(UCFCOURSEID)
WHERE 
    ep.exper_id = '1492'
    AND mv.md_id = mp.md_id 
    AND ce.exper_id = ep.exper_id 
    AND ce.completed_id = mv.completed_id 
    AND mv.md_option_id = mo.md_option_id 
    AND ce.list_version_id = lv.list_version_id 
GROUP BY 
    s.did, s.cid, s.lid, ep.exper_id, ep.exper_name,
    mp.md_id, mp.md_name, mo.md_option_id, mo.md_option_order, 
    mo.md_option_name, ce.student_id, mv.text_answer, mv.md_value_id,
    mv.completed_id, CE.YID, kk.external_id
```

The rest is where values and group by

Comment: There are 2 errors in the code you posted.  You have two commas before the `COUNT()` and you also need to give the `COUNT()` an alias to use it as a subquery. e.g. `COUNT(ce.times_observed) AS CountOfTimes`

Comment: It's really a [bad habbit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) using `,` in the `from` but combining that with outer-joins also instead of the ancient `*=` syntax is bizarre. Why don't you just add the condition to the `where` clause of the existing query? also it would help to [TAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) your RDBMS

Comment: i corrected the errors. i cant put in the query , they are creating new. so i tried to do subquery as i showed but didnt worked

Comment: And what is your RDBMS? also `Select ,` is another typo.

Comment: SQL Server  Studio

Comment: Honestly it would be easier to start over here. There are some many logical, syntax and antiquated syntax issues going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can make this easier is to utilise *apply* which provides the derived column you can then both include in your *select* list and reference in your *where* clause.

Here is an example:

```
select ..., cour, ...
from ...
cross apply (
  select case when kid='7180' then '044986' when kid='7800' then '044984' end
)c(cour)
where ...
  and cour = @cour
group by...
```

Comment: what is c in c(cour) ? and what about left joins? gives error for 'kid', says invalid column

Comment: `c` is an alias. Just include the `left join`s in the  `from` clause as normal - eg `cross apply (...)c(cour) left join.... where...` I'd also strongly recommend using `inner join` syntax also instead of comma-separated tables and conditions in the `where` clause

Comment: The multi-part identifier "s.kid" could not be bound.                                                           Invalid column name 'cid'.  i have errors or that?

Comment: You must make sure the `apply` appears *after* the other tables in the `from` clause - put the apply after all other tables inc the outer joins.

Comment: yes, perfect. it worked for 'year'. But the 'cour' value is in left join table .That's why doesn't work for that :/

Comment: No it will work, you must have the cross apply before the left join; move it after the left join.

Comment: unfortunetly, i couldnt make it while its left join. i will add my code with error, please check

Comment: You are not using the correct syntax, nowhere above in my example is there "as alias" in the cross apply, and you've changed the names of the columns and the aliases in the example you've posted making it even harder to help you.

Comment: im sorry, i wanted to keep short. now corrected

Comment: you still have not used the correct syntax. Please see [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/4HRkoII4) showing a functioning left join with this method. Hopefully you can apply this to your situation.